# SQLAlchemy: Problems Migrating to PostgreSQL from SQLite (e.g. sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError:)

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am having difficulties migrating a working a working script to PGSQL from SQLite. I am using SQLalchemy. When I run the script, it raises the following errors:

```
raise exc.DBAPIError.instance(statement, parameters, e, connection_invalidated=is_disconnect)

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) can't adapt 'INSERT INTO cnn_hot_stocks (datetime, list, ticker, price, change, "pctChange") VALUES (%(datetime)s, %(list)s, %(ticker)s, %(price)s, %(change)s, %(pctChange)s)' {'price': Decimal('7.94'), 'list': 'active', 'datetime': datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 23, 11, 45, 1, 544361), 'pctChange': u'+1.53%', 'ticker': u'BAC', 'change': Decimal('0.12')}
```

The insert call works well when using sqlite engine, but I want to use pgsql to utilize the native Decimal type for keeping financial data correct. I copied the script and just changed the db engine to my postgresql server. Any advice on how to troubleshoot this error would be greatly appreciated for this SQLalchemy newbie... I think I am up a creek on this one! Thanks in advance!

Here are my relevant code segments and table descriptions:

```
dbstring = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/algo"
db = create_engine(dbstring)
db.echo = True  # Try changing this to True and see what happens
metadata = MetaData(db)

cnn_hot_stocks = Table('cnn_hot_stocks', metadata, autoload=True)

i = cnn_hot_stocks.insert() # running log from cnn hot stocks web-site

def scrape_data():
    try:
            html = urllib2.urlopen('http://money.cnn.com/data/hotstocks/').read()
            markup, errors = tidy_document(html)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(markup,)
    except Exception as e:
            pass
    list_map = { 2 : 'active',
                 3 : 'gainer',
                 4 : 'loser'
               }
    # Iterate over 3 tables on CNN hot stock web-site
    for x in range(2, 5):
            table = soup('table')[x]
            for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
                    timestamp = datetime.now()
                    col = row.findAll('td')
                    ticker = col[0].a.string
                    price = Decimal(col[1].span.string)
                    change = Decimal(col[2].span.span.string)
                    pctChange = col[3].span.span.string
                    log_data = {'datetime'  : timestamp,
                                'list'      : list_map[x],
                                'ticker'    : ticker,
                                'price'     : price,
                                'change'    : change,
                                'pctChange' : pctChange
                               }
                    print log_data
                    # Commit to DB
                    i.execute(log_data)
```

TABLE:

```
cnn_hot_stocks = Table('cnn_hot_stocks', metadata, # log of stocks data on cnn hot stocks lists
            Column('datetime', DateTime, primary_key=True),
            Column('list', String), # loser/gainer/active
            Column('ticker', String),
            Column('price', Numeric),
            Column('change', Numeric),
            Column('pctChange', String),
            )
```

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is, as I do not know the `postgresql`. But very often it can be related to the format of the columns being inserted, so I suggest you try to create a temporary table on `postgresql` with only 1 column (`ticker`) and see if inserting works. If it does, then add columns one-by-one and see which one is the cause of the problem. If already inserting one string column does not work, then it should indicate that there is something wrong with the syntax of the query (although it looks good to me).

Comment: Thanks van, appreciate it, I tried out your advice and every column worked... I re-vamped the way I am doing things and was able to get it working by mapping the tables to classes and building the new rows by instantiating the class, setting the attribute values, then committing the changes to the db. I am still not sure why the first way would not work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My reading of the documentation is that you have to use `numeric` instead of `decimal.`

PostgreSQL has no type named `decimal` (it's an alias for numeric but not a very full-featured one), and SQL Alchemy seems to expect `numeric` as the type it can use for abstraction purposes.

Comment: It has been a while, but I just wanted to follow up, that was indeed correct, using the numeric type in postgres made the difference.